# Trying to organize values between elements with user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first post. I'm working on a webapp that will sort five distinct values between five elements, but I'm not sure how best to do it.

There are five select box elements with five values shared between them. I'll refer to them as elements 1-5 and values A-E. The goal is to have each value used only once between all five elements. So if I have:

1=A, 2=B, 3=C, and the user changes the value in element 2 from B to A, element 1 needs to change to B so that each value only appears once.

My current idea is to try to use a single function that triggers by onchange from each element, gets the new value from the triggering element, then finds the other element with the same value and updates it to use the unused value. Each select box looks like this:

```
<select id="1" onchange="updateElements(this);">
```

Then the function would look something like this:

```
function updateElements(trigger)
{
    var new_value = document.getElementById('trigger').value;

    // here we check all the elements minus the trigger to find one
    // with a value that matches new_value, but how? Then we go to...

    // here where we compare all of the values of the elements against
    // the list of all values to determine which one isn't being used

    // finally we set the element that had the matching value to use
    // the unused value
    document.getElementById('matchingelement').value = 'unused_value';
}
```

I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to check all of the elements to find one with a matching value, nor can I figure out how to compare the used values to determine which one is unused.

Any ideas? Also please feel free to tell me if I'm on the wrong track altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using jQuery, as it is one of your question's tags.

```
var previous_value;
$('select').focus(function(e) {

    previous_value = $(this).val();

}).change(function(e) {

    var new_value = $(this).val();
    $('select:contains(' + new_value + ')').not($(this)).val(previous_value);  

});
```

I thought of something like this. As soon as you focus a select-element, its current value gets saved in the variable `previous_value`. On a change, its new value is being saved into `new_value`. At the same time it sets the value of the select-element that has the new text in it to the previous_value. Also it double-checks if the selected element is not this element.

I suppose this is about what you wanted.

Comment: Your logic is more complete than mine. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use inline JS click handlers unless you have to:

```
$('#1').change(function() {...}
```

Then, use jQuery if you're using jQuery:

```
function updateElements(trigger) {
    var new_value = $('#trigger').value;
    ...
    $('#matchingelement').value = 'unused_value';
}
```

I think you're on the right track. I'd use something like this to get each select's value:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var my_val = $(this).val();

    $('select').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() == my_val ) {
            $(this).val( unused_val );
            return
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Updated with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need some conditionals...

grab your values

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("1");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("2");
```

etc...

then cross check your elements

```
if(elem1 = "a")

{
  elem2.value="blah";
}else{change elements accordingly}
```

you can check for null as well

if you want some real examples of drop down value checking i can upload them